# NOT IN Subquery Optimization

Tags: sql-server

I have a dynamic query that runs indentifying CDs that members have not rented yet. I am using the NOT IN subquery but when I have large member table it makes them really slow. Any suggestions how to optimize the query

```
SELECT DVDTitle AS "DVD Title" 
FROM DVD 
WHERE DVDId NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DVDId FROM Rental WHERE MemberId = AL240);
```

thanks

Comment: What are the table definitions including column nullability and indexes?

Comment: Do you have an index on `Rental(MemberID, DVDId)`?

Comment: give us more information, like the number of rows, indexes, and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS` will have slightly better performance because it can "short circuit" rather than evaluating the entire set for each match. At the very least, it will be "no worse" than `NOT IN` or an `OUTER JOIN`, though there are exceptions to every rule. Here is how I would write this query:

```
SELECT DVDTitle AS [DVD Title] 
  FROM dbo.DVD AS d
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Rental 
     WHERE MemberId = 'AL240'
     AND DVDId = d.DVDId
  );
```

I would guess you will optimize performance better by investigating the execution plan and ensuring that your indexes are best suited for this query (without causing negative impact to other parts of your workload).

Also see [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: If neither `DVDId` column is nullable I would expect `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` to have the same plan. If either are nullable the `NOT IN` version [needs to do more work though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, that's true, but notice that I also eliminated the `DISTINCT`

Comment: Just default to NOT EXIST always if you're unsure. It's pretty much always the best choice for anti joins.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DVDTitle AS "DVD Title" 
FROM DVD d
left outer join Rental r on d.DVDId = r.DVDId
WHERE r.MemberId = 'AL240'
    and r.DVDId is null
```

Make sure you have indexes on:

```
d.DVDId
r.DVDId
r.MemberId
```

Comment: @K-Seeker Out of curiosity, did you observe an actual performance improvement here?

Comment: Hi Aaron, there was a significant inprovement. I have not tested your suugestion yet but I tried the NOT EXISTS and it was not that much difference than the NO IN subquery. I will keep you posted. thanks again. Dan